# Crontab execution of multiple commands but last command is omitted

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I know how to execute multiple command in one crontab line but I can't understand why my last command is not being executed. My (root) crontab is like

```
5 0 1,15 * * echo $(date) >> /root/certbot_cronjob_log.txt && /usr/services/certbot/certbot-auto renew --text >>/root/certbot_cronjob_log.txt 2>&1 && service nginx restart
```

What I want to achieve: Write the current date to file certbot_cronjob_log.txt, then run the autorenew script "certbot-auto", write it's output into the file and then restart nginx.

It does everything until the point "restart nginx". When I run exactly this whole command in my terminal (as root) it is working and nginx restarts.

I already tried this:

```
5 0 1,15 * * bash -c 'echo $(date) >> /root/certbot_cronjob_log.txt && /usr/services/certbot/certbot-auto renew --text >>/root/certbot_cronjob_log.txt 2>&1 && service nginx restart'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a bash script and run that via cron instead - that will probably have better results..

Comment: Probably because `/usr/sbin` (where the `service` command lives) isn't in the crontab path - same likely applies to `/sbin/restart`. (Even if you move your commands to a separate script you will need to address this, either by using full paths to the executables or by defining a suitable `PATH`)

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. `/usr/sbin/service nginx restart` did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

The `/usr/sbin` directory (where the upstart `service` command lives) isn't in the default crontab path, so you will either need to add an explicit `PATH` assignment in the top of your crontab file e.g.:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

or use the full path in your command

```
/usr/sbin/service nginx restart
```

You will need to do this whether you keep it as an in-line command or break it out into a shell script (although you'd then have the choice of setting the `PATH` in the script versus in the crontab file).

---

FWIW since variants of this question are frequently asked, here's the default cron environment on my 16.04 system, obtained by running `/usr/bin/printenv > /tmp/cronenv` from root's crontab:

```
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/root
```

Note how minimal it is - this is often why commands or scripts that run fine in an interactive shell fail when run from cron.