# Running bash script through crontab results in diffrent results

Tags: bash, cron, services

i made a really simple script to ensure my important services are active.

```
#!/bin/bash
services=(apache2 sendmail mysql)
for service in "${services[@]}"
do
        if [[ $(service $service status | grep running) ]]; then
                echo $service " is active" >> /home/user/logging.txt
        else
                echo "!!!!" $service " is not active!!!!" >> /home/user/logging.txt
        fi
done
```

When i run the script manually, everything works fine, active services get logged as active and inactive services logged as inactive.

For automating the script i made an entry in crontab:

```
0 10 * * * /usr/bin/service-check
```

The script runs but the output generated in the logging file is not correct!
The output in the loggingfile says for every Service:
`!!! servicename is not active !!!`

i repeated the steps several times same result over again...

Output of the logging file:

```
!!!! apache2  is not active!!!!
!!!! sendmail  is not active!!!!
!!!! mysql  is not active!!!!
apache2  is active
sendmail  is active
mysql  is active
```

The first three lines are from crontab, the last three from manual start...
This really grind my gears and i can't figure out whats wrong... any idea?

Comment: Why don't you include `$(service $service status | grep running)` into the log? ;-)

Comment: See [Crontab execution of multiple commands but last command is omitted](https://askubuntu.com/a/936165/178692)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be finding service.

You may need to specify SHELL and PATH variables like

```
SHELL=/bin/bash; 
PATH=<copy from your current $PATH that works>
```

before you add e.g

```
0 10 * * * /usr/bin/service-check
```