# Cannot reload a service with cron in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cron

I have a script that updates my ssl certificates and reloads squid to make it update its certificate once it is regenerated:

```
certbot renew
service squid reload
```

I put it to /etc/cron.monthly/certbot-renew.sh to make it run monthly as root.

The certificates are updated, but squid stops working each time its certificate is changed. If I do

```
service squid reload
```

manually it starts to work. I cannot figure out what is happening because there is only the information on manual squid reload in syslog:

```
sudo grep squid /var/log/syslog
Dec 23 20:39:11 localhost squid[8363]:  * Reloading Squid HTTP Proxy configuration files
Dec 23 20:39:11 localhost squid[8363]:    ...done.
```

The command

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

does not show anything concerning to squid.

what is wrong with cron? If I run the script manually

```
sudo ./certbot-renew.sh
```

squid is restarted and "Reloading Squid ..." appears in syslog.

See [how I installed certbot](https://developernote.com/2017/07/securing-nginx-with-lets-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04/) and [how I installed squid](https://developernote.com/2018/01/setting-up-squid-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to take the entire picture of what I do.

Comment: Possibly related? [Crontab execution of multiple commands but last command is omitted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936073/crontab-execution-of-multiple-commands-but-last-command-is-omitted)

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with reloading nginx via cron. It seems like the `service ...` command is completely ignored. Nothing in syslog, nothing in nginx logs.

I switched to using `systemctl reload nginx` instead, and this seems to work.